# Can a virtual type be used as a dependency for a class?

Tags: magento2, di, object-manager, virtualtype

I'm trying to do something new with virtual types. I understand that you can create these in your `di.xml` and use them as arguments for other types in `di.xml`. But can I also declare a virtual type and use it in a constructor in a PHP class?

For example: I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler"
             type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filePath" xsi:type="string">/var/log/custom.log</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

And:

```
public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler $logger
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

But this does not work. I also tried:

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler" type="custom_logger"/>
<virtualType name="custom_logger"
             type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filePath" xsi:type="string">/var/log/custom.log</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

With the same PHP code, but the results are the same. I get a `ReflectionException` that class `Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler` does not exist.

I find this odd, because the way I always understood, the Object Manager uses reflection to see what classes are required in the constructur, and uses the `di.xml` configuration on it's turn to bring this back to a class. So why isn't this working with a virtual type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're trying won't work because php must be able to find the class that you are giving in a constructor argument's type hint. This is part of the language and can't be overriden. Php is unaware of `di.xml` settings.

The object that Object Manager passes to a constructor must implement or inherit from the given type hint. In the case of virtual types, object manager creates an instance of the underlying class with the given configuration and passes this into a constructor.

The class receiving the virtual type as an argument must use the underlying class (or an ancestor/interface) for the argument's type hint. This must be a concrete class/interface that php understands. Hence, The virtual type itself does not actually exist, it's just a shortcut for use in configuration xml only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve almost what you want and you should get the type hinting. Aaron is correct though, the virtual class won't exist so you can't require it directly from the constructor.

If your class consturctor looks like this

```php
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

You could add the following to your di.xml

```xml
<virtualType name="MyCustomLogger" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="debug" xsi:type="object">Foo\Bar\Logger\Handler\DebugHandler</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Path\To\Class\That\Requires\Logger">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">MyCustomLogger</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```